# Regression with categorical variable

Tags: pandas, regression, one-hot-encoding

I want to achieve regression with a categorical variable. I have my dataset like this:

```
item_id    rating     gender
1            4          F
2            3          M
3            2          M

model = ols("rating ~ C(gender) + genre", data = data).fit()
```

Output:

```
========================================================================================
                           coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept                3.5175      0.012    295.935      0.000       3.494       3.541
C(gender)[T.M]          -0.0021      0.008     -0.257      0.797      -0.018       0.014
genre[T.Adventure]      -0.0275      0.017     -1.622      0.105      -0.061       0.006
genre[T.Animation]       0.0064      0.027      0.240      0.810      -0.046       0.058
genre[T.Childrens]       0.0134      0.020      0.657      0.511      -0.027       0.054
genre[T.Comedy]          0.0293      0.014      2.130      0.033       0.002       0.056
```

Although this gives a correct output it just gives the interaction between gender in general and I would like to get it for each gender separately, so to see the interaction of the female gender and the male gender.

I have tried to encode the gender as you would do with a categorical variable:

```
item_id    rating     gender
1            4          0
2            3          1
3            2          1
```

but it still does not give the desired output.

Comment: Your provided dataframe has a column named `gender` but your model includes a column named `genre` (in French). Is this a typo?

Comment: use a glm general linear model and Binomial family

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

item_id =[1,2,3]
rating=[4,3,2]
gender=[0,1,1]

df=pd.DataFrame({'item_id':item_id, 'rating':rating,'gender':gender})

X=df[['rating']]
y=np.array(df['gender'])

logreg=LogisticRegression(C=100)
logreg.fit(X,y)
y_predictions=logreg.predict_proba(X)[:,1]
auc=roc_auc_score(y, y_predictions)

print("Area under the curve: ", auc)

print(y_predictions)

y_pred2 = logreg.predict(X)

cm = confusion_matrix(y,y_pred2)
print(cm)

probable outcomes:
[0.05623715 0.94397376 0.99979014]
confusion matrix
[[1 0]
 [0 2]]

data frame
   item_id  rating  gender
0        1       4       0
1        2       3       1
2        3       2       1
```